# save folder with integer variable name in document directory

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I want a folder in document directory with constant name. Now i want to save the folder with a variable name, like i have an variable "n" and the value of "n" is changeable now I want to save the folder with the name of "n" value.
my code is as follow but it give me error.

```
 NSInteger n = 3;    
 NSError *error;

NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *dataPath = [aDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"%d",n];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: what is the `Error` ?

Comment: too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *dataPath = [aDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",n];
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in the line below

```
NSString *dataPath = [aDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"%d",n];
```

It should be

```
NSString *dataPath = [aDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",n]];
```